# fadeToggle malfunctioning when combined with animate:width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please see: http://jsfiddle.net/neowot/z1xxsu8t/2/ (prepare for an ugly website, lol)

Click on the dropdown and choose "1". Then type something into the textbox and hit enter. You should see the "LeftPanel" div now.

Now click on the circular skyblue button. Here is where the problem begins.

LeftPanel's width decreases as desired. But instead of RightPanel and SideBarSearchDiv smoothly fading in simultaneously, they act really weird.

When you click on the circular button again, the same weird behavior happens.

The JS code in question is under the comment "Relevant Code Here".

I tried to fix this by using the code under the comment "Try2". That code works really well for the *first* click of the button, but still glitches for the second click.

Can I get help with getting the toggleWidth and fadeToggle animations run smoothly and look good? They don't necessarily have to be run simultaneously, so long as it looks proper.

Thank you.

```
//Relevant Code Here

    $('#SearchIcon').click(function() {


        /*Try 1 */
        var toggleWidth = $("#LeftPanel").width() == 380 ? "1000px" : "380px"; 
        $('#LeftPanel').animate( {'width': toggleWidth}, 1000);              
        $('#SideBarSearchDiv').fadeToggle(500, resize);
        $('#RightPanel').fadeToggle(500, resize);   




        /*Try 2
        var toggleWidth = $("#LeftPanel").width() == 380 ? "1000px" : "380px"; 
        $('#LeftPanel').animate( {'width': toggleWidth}, 1000, function() {
                $('#SideBarSearchDiv').fadeToggle(500, resize);
                $('#RightPanel').fadeToggle(500, resize);                           
        }); */

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can handle it with only one behavior, there's a lot going on and since your animating a parent element with child elements, it's hard to follow.

But you already have an if condition, so one solution would be to use it to make different animations for showing and hiding. Like this:

```
if ($("#LeftPanel").width() == 1000) {

            $('#LeftPanel').animate({
                'width': '380px'
            }, 1000, function () {
                $('#SideBarSearchDiv').fadeToggle(500, resize);
                $('#RightPanel').fadeToggle(500, resize);
            });
        } else {

            $('#SideBarSearchDiv, #RightPanel').fadeToggle(500, function () {
                $('#LeftPanel').animate({
                    'width': '1000px'
                }, 1000);
                resize

            });
        }
```

See jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/psxrwh7s/